# Rewrite policies in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I'm contacting you because I'm having issues migrating an Apache + PHP app to Azure.

I was using Apache rewrite module to read the Request URIs and transform them to correct URLs. I've translated those instructions into IIS rewrite rules,  but I can't make them work in Azure.

The rules were:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)\.json$ $1.json.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-add$ $1_procesar.php?abm_accion=a [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-edit\-(.*)$ $1_procesar.php?abm_accion=m&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-delete\-(.*)$ $1_procesar.php?abm_accion=d&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-add$ index.php?put=$1_am&abm_accion=a [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-edit\-(.*)$ index.php?put=$1_am&abm_accion=m&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(css|js|favicon|img|php|json|icon|process|report|fonts|ckeditor)
RewriteRule ^(zpanel\/)(.*)$ index.php?put=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So I've translated them to:

```
<rewrite  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <clear/>
        <rule name="rule 1d" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\.json$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}{R:2}.json.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule 1l" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-add$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}{R:2}_procesar.php?abm_accion=a" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule 1x" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-edit\-(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}{R:2}_procesar.php?abm_accion=m&amp;id={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule 1U" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-delete\-(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}{R:2}_procesar.php?abm_accion=d&amp;id={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule 1S" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-add$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}index.php?put={R:2}_am&amp;abm_accion=a" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule 1V" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-edit\-(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}index.php?put={R:2}_am&amp;abm_accion=m&amp;id={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/css|js|favicon|img|php|json|icon|process|report|fonts|ckeditor$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}index.php?q={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

But after this, I keep having the same error message in Azure. "The resource cannot be found".

Are the translations OK? Do I need to change something else to make it work on the Azure version of IIS?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and error message, I guess you may have some error on your translations result.

As far as I know, IIS has a [url rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), which could tranlate the rewrite role.

I tranlate the rewrite role as below(not as same as yours), I suggest you could use below codes and try again:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\.json$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.json.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-add$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}_procesar.php?abm_accion=a" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-edit\-(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}_procesar.php?abm_accion=m&amp;id={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-process\-delete\-(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}_procesar.php?abm_accion=d&amp;id={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-add$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?put={R:1}_am&amp;abm_accion=a" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)\-edit\-(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?put={R:1}_am&amp;abm_accion=m&amp;id={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(zpanel\/)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(css|js|favicon|img|php|json|icon|process|report|fonts|ckeditor)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?put={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You could click the url rewrite module in the IIS explorer firstly.

Then you could find import rule at right side. Click the button you will find the translate windows.

[image]